Google CCAI Platform: IVR with Dialogflow CX not initiating virtual agent automatically
I'm working on an IVR integration using Google CCAI (Contact Center AI) Platform with Dialogflow CX. My goal is to have the IVR automatically call customers and connect them to a virtual agent queue when I upload a campaign. However, I'm encountering an issue with the current flow:
1.The call goes to a human agent first.
2.The human agent then initiates the call to the customer.
3.The human agent manually transfers the call to the virtual agent.
Expected behavior:
When I upload a campaign, the IVR should directly call the customer and connect them to the virtual agent queue without human intervention.
Current behavior:
The process involves unnecessary human agent interaction, which defeats the purpose of automation.
Questions:
1.Is there a configuration setting I'm missing that would allow the IVR to initiate calls directly to customers?
2.How can I set up the campaign to automatically route calls to the virtual agent queue without human agent involvement?
3.Are there any specific CCAI or Dialogflow CX features I should be utilizing to achieve this automated flow?
